# Solving a simple Inequality

Tags: inequality, problem-solving

I have a probability problem and I am given $P(X^2-12x+35>0)$ I know $X^2-12x+35>0$ can be factored into $(x-5)(x-7)>0$

The probabilities that it says I need are $P(x>7$ or $x<5)$

When I look at solving the inequality it looks like it should be $x>5$ and $x>7$

How do you get $x<5$

Comment: $(x-5)(x-7) > 0 \iff ((x-5)>0 \land (x-7)>0) \lor ((x-5)<0 \land (x-7)<0) \\ \iff (x > 5 \land x > 7) \lor (x < 5\land x < 7) \iff (x > 7) \lor (x < 5)$

Comment: You can try to plot the quadratic function $f(x) = x^{2} -12x + 35$ and see when does $f(x) > 0$

Answer (score 0):

Your question has nothing to do with probability; it's really just about the inequality $(x-5)(x-7)\gt0$.  In order for the product of two quantities, $x-5$ and $x-7$, to be positive, either each quantity is positive or each quantity is negative. (That is, the product of two negative numbers is positive.)  If $x\gt7$, then each is positive; if $5\lt x\lt 7$, then $x-5$ is positive while $x-7$ is negative; and if $x\lt5$, then each is negative.  That's why you get $(x-5)(x-7)\gt0$ if and only if $x\gt7$ or $x\lt5$.